# How to do Data Ingestion to Kustos Database from Application Insights Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

I am using application insights and capturing telemetry data for various actions in my application . Using Kustolab , I am able to create databases and table . Now how to get the data from my application insights resource to the Kustodatabase  . I am unable to find any documentation too on this one . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: @yonisha apparently it is the former name of App. Insights Analytics, see  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/28/introducing-application-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Your telemetry data which is sent Application Insights is also available for query in Application Insights Analytics. You will see in the Analytics portal the different tables which hold the telemetry data. Nothing else is required from you. Just query it.

See the documentation for more info:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/

Dan